# Community Promotion Ads - 2016

Tags: discussion, community-ads

It's 2016 now, and we've [made some changes to the sidebar size](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272563/were-standardizing-the-sidebar-width-at-300px-on-all-sites). As such, we can now restart the Community Promotion Ads for 2016!

Keep in mind, we have updated some of the guidelines compared to previously - the changes are marked in bold in the Image Requirements section.

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- interesting chemistry research sites
- useful resources for practitioner and student alike
- the site's twitter account
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **300 x 250 pixels**, or double that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of **150 KB**
- **If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.**

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/3079).

Answer (score 16):

[image: The Periodic Table. Come chat with us!]

Comment: Chemistry is much better, Chemistry is way better, still Chemistry is better

Comment: *Hey that's my room you're talking about*

Comment: @Jan Is it better now?

Comment: Yes! \*upvotes\*

Answer (score 12):

[image: Visit our meta site!]

Comment: The community? **Meta is murder.**

Comment: [There was a place holder once.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/H5NFu.png)

Comment: The layered source can be found on my [deviantart profile](http://sirconrade.deviantart.com/art/Meta-ad-dev-585374149).

Comment: May I ask how you achieved that peeling effect? Is there a specific GIMP effect to do that or did you follow a specific guide?

Comment: @Christian I am sorry, but I can't find the guide I used to learn that any more. I created the corner with inkscape, basically shading in a stretched triangle with various layers. I had to rework the thing a couple of times until I was pleased. The product I then imported into gimp to resize and adjust it. It is probably not the most efficient way to do it, but it got the job done. There are quite a few guides where you can cheat off of, so if you try to do it, just take your time and let your creativity do the rest.

Answer (score 11):

[image: AIST Spectral Database for Organic Compounds]

Comment: Composited from the SDBS website header, org name from one of their PDFs, and an IR spectrum of naphthalene.

Comment: Nice, but why an IR? ;)

Comment: @Jan Well, mainly because I'm noodling most at vibrational modes at the moment, out of all the spectroscopies. Also, because I think it makes a nicer picture than does NMR. <grin>

Comment: Wait, lemme retract my upvote ;)

Comment: @Jan NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO!!!!!!

Comment: Updated to nicer image, composited in MS Powerpoint 2010. Retained the IR spectrum specifically to spite @Jan.

Answer (score 10):

[image: Detexify: automated LaTeX symbol recognition]

Comment: [Originally posted in Physics](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/7442/8563).

Answer (score 10):

[image: Avogadro - the open molecular editor]

Answer (score 10):

[image: Current Chemistry Stack Exchange bounties]
<sub>(source: [herokuapp.com](http://stack-exchange-dynamic-ads.herokuapp.com/chemistry.stackexchange.com/bounty.png))</sub>

Answer (score 8):

[image: Digital Open Access Identifier - a DOI resolver that prioritizes open access]

Comment: [Inkscape SVG source](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60184856/Stack%20Exchange%20Community%20Ads/doai%20ad%202016.svg).

Answer (score 7):

[image: Retraction Watch]

Comment: From http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/a/2153/21869

Answer (score 7):

[image: Academia Stack Exchange]

Comment: Design elements shamelessly stolen from [academia.se]. [Inkscape SVG source](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60184856/Stack%20Exchange%20Community%20Ads/academia%20ad%202016.svg).

Answer (score 7):

[image: History of Science and Mathematics at Stack Exchange]

Comment: [Inkscape SVG source](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60184856/Stack%20Exchange%20Community%20Ads/hsm%20ad%202016.svg), working off of [this image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b8/Diophantus_title_I_1621.jpg).

Answer (score 7):

[image: Computational Science at Stack Exchange]

Comment: [Inkscape SVG source](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60184856/Stack%20Exchange%20Community%20Ads/scicomp%20ad%202016.svg).

Comment: | sed "s/end do/end life/"

Comment: @Martin - as I said on physics, offended programmers please apply to /dev/null/ ;-).

Answer (score 7):

[image: Earth Science on Stack Exchange]

Answer (score 7):

[image: NIST CompChem Comparison & Benchmark Database]

Comment: Composed from scratch using WordArt in MS Powerpoint 2010, following the form of the logo  and header on the site. NIST logo taken from a Google Images search.

Answer (score 6):

[image: Let's do the bounty dance! Enter your favourite question today!]

Comment: Can't believe there is an ads for the bounty dance

Comment: +1; The best of lots...... why don't we have this at the physics community:(

Comment: Haha I'm close to tears.

Answer (score 6):

[image: Discover our universe]

Answer (score 5):

[image: Proposal for Science Educators SE]
<sub>(source: [stackexchange.com](http://area51.stackexchange.com/ads/proposal/102351.png))</sub>

Answer (score 4):

[image: arxiv.org: the leading open access e-print repository]

Comment: [Originally posted on Physics](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/7439/8563). @user36790 - attribution would be nice :-).

Comment: @E.P: Sorry for that; yes 've taken it from Emilio Pisanty's  [answer](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/7439/36790).

Comment: No worries. And in case the initials didn't give it away, network profiles are usually clear enough ;-P. No need to name explicitly - just link back to where you found it :-).

Comment: @E.P.: actually  was unsure about how the community would react on Arxiv  ad; since I've not found it in 2015; I would wait and see- till now the response is positive:)

Answer (score 4):

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]

Comment: [Zipped source - Inkscape SVG and Mathematica notebook](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60184856/Stack%20Exchange%20Community%20Ads/dlmf%20ad.zip)

Answer (score 3):

[image: Follow us on Twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted, now with 80px more width! It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting.

Comment: The downvote tradition begins ;P

Comment: Dear template answer, $$\text{Please try not to get downvoted too much.}$$ Sincerely, MAR

Answer (score 3):

[image: AnkiDroid: Open source flashcards app]

Answer (score -1):

[image: Auto-Latex Equations add-on for Google Docs]

Comment: Doesn't work for me

Comment: It doesn't work on mobile, but the link should lead to a Google Doc, which leads to the Google Docs add-on store.

Comment: What is this even supposed to be? Two arrows coming out of a document pointing to $\mathrm{\LaTeX}$? What are you selling. $\mathrm{\LaTeX}$?